# Image becomes white strokes, what's the proper way to overlay a texture in shader nodes?

Tags: texturing, shaders

I'm trying to place a label with the image texture node. The label is in black. After importing the image it becomes transparent with white strokes.

How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Hello I guess you need to use the Alpha output as factor in your mix node, if it does not work please pack your image and share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image preview, the alpha channel is what you need. In the simplest setup, you would mix two colors using the alpha channel as the factor. The mix output can be fed into the *Base Color* input of the *Principled BSDF* as shown below.

[image: Mix 1]

You can take this a step further by using the same *Alpha* output to mix two values for the *Roughness* as shown below.

[image: Mix 2]

---

If you would like to know why the *Color* output of the image produces a gray outline, in the *Image Editor*, set the *Display Channels* to *Color*. You'll notice that the color is mostly black except for the outlines which will most likely be gray.

[image: Color]